# Is it possible to get the list of rows grouped together by a column name in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pydal

In my database, I have a table called 'results' with four columns (name,device,passed,failed). Suppose if there are 4 rows in the table as below.

```
name   device   passed failed

test1  device_1    2      1
test1  device_2    3      0
test2  device_1    1      2
test2  device_2    2      1
```

I want the below result:

```
[(test1,device_1,2,1),(test1,device_2,3,0)]
[(test2,device_1,1,2),(test1,device_2,2,1)]
```

Is it possible to get that result with only one query to DB?

currently I am querying database twice, first getting a list of distinct names and then getting rows with that name. Below is the pseudo code.

```
 test_names = SELECT DISTINCT name FROM results
 for test_name in test_names: 
      rows = SELECT * FROM results WHERE name=test_name
```

then I am processing rows to get the object structure that I wanted.

Comment: I would normally handle this kind of thing in the presentation layer. I don't know Python, so I can't say more than that

Answer (score 1):

You need concatenation functions like `CONCAT_WS()` and `CONCAT` to concatenate the columns of each row and then aggregation with `GROUP_CONCAT()` for each `name`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', CONCAT_WS(',', name, device, passed, failed), ')')), ']') AS result
FROM results
GROUP BY name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=41c38e331698bba483e6fabd92ad5a33).

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('(',name,',',device,',',passed,',',failed,')') FROM results group by name;
```